# .datepicker('setdate') issues, in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a function that executes a query to get some data based on a certain date range which is selected using .datepicker().  I am trying to set the datepicker's that are in the response data back to the date range which was selected before the query was executed.

```
queryDate = '2009-11-01';
$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', queryDate);
```

has the interesting result of setting the datepicker to today's date!  I wouldn't be so confused if it just spit out an error.  Why does it set it to today's date?

**How can I take the date which is formated like, 'yyyy-mm-dd' and set the datepicker to it?**

I am thinking it might be best to just set the text-box which the datepicker is linked to to 'queryDate'.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you would like to support really old browsers you should parse the date string, since using the ISO8601 date format with the `Date` constructor is not supported pre IE9:

```js
var queryDate = '2009-11-01',
    dateParts = queryDate.match(/(\d+)/g)
    realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);  
                                    // months are 0-based!
// For >= IE9
var realDate = new Date('2009-11-01');  

$('#datePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); // format to show
$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', realDate);
```

Check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/iyiwe).

Comment: You missed a bit: `$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', realDate);`

Comment: Do not parse date by your self. This is bad approach. Better use datepicker parseDate function. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Hollister are you sure the `parseDate` utility existed when the earlier answer was written? I agree though, always prefer existing code, if it works.

Comment: Did anyone had any issues with IE8? Using the same technique `$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', realDate);` seems that I'm getting some issues.

Comment: Only browsers not supporting using a date string in the date contructor should not really be considdered

Answer (score 75):

When you trying to call setDate you must provide valid javascript Date object.

```
queryDate = '2009-11-01';

var parsedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', queryDate);

$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', parsedDate);
```

This will allow you to use different formats for query date and string date representation in datepicker. This approach is very helpful when you create multilingual site. Another helpful function is formatDate, which formats javascript date object to string.

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings );
```

Comment: +1 Much better than the accepted answer. Too bad SO doesn't have a way to indicate that a better answer came in (in this case years later) subsequent to the answer that was accepted.

Comment: @Hollister, you can flag the question for a moderator to take a look, of course explaining that the later answer is better. I think moderators can change answer acceptance.

Answer (score 11):

As Scobal's post implies, the datepicker is looking for a Date object - not just a string! So, to modify your example code to do what you want:

```
var queryDate = new Date('2009/11/01'); // Dashes won't work
$('#datePicker').datepicker('setDate', queryDate);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. And would rather use the built-in Date object than some DIY parser as per CMS' solution

Comment: However, the current docs state: The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format. You set the format when creating the datepicker with .datepicker({ dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd' }); and yet this does not work - is this a bug, an error with the documentation or something else?

Answer (score 7):

Try changing it to:

```
queryDate = '2009-11-01';
$('#datePicker').datepicker({defaultDate: new Date (queryDate)});
```

Comment: For some reason, this works better than setDate. In my case, setDate cleared input on some random interval, but defaultDate works everytime.

Answer (score 2):

```
function calenderEdit(dob) {
    var date= $('#'+dob).val();
    $("#dob").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true, yearRange: '1950:+10'
    }).datepicker("setDate", date);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what is was looking for, ty sir

Answer (score 1):

Check that the date you are trying to set it to lies within the allowed date range if the minDate or maxDate options are set.