# JQuery Datepicker set input[type="text"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ok i have a `<input id="has-assigned-date">`, I want to set or put the default value. The value from the db when fetched it should be on the input box this will occur on page ready. Sorry for the poor english...

Here's my code:

```
$("#has-assigned-date").datepicker({ 
   minDate: -20, 
   maxDate: "+12M +10D" , 
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",      
   defaultDate: dd, 
   setDate: (def[2] - 1) + "/" + def[1] + "/" + def[0]});
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953840/datepickersetdate-issues-in-jquery hope this will help you.

Comment: @MANISH LANGA I tried the sameple given but still wont set the value of the textbox to the data I fetch from the DB...

Comment: @Vikram on the edit version you made it still doesn't show the value on the textbox...hmmm... when loading the page the textbox must have that value..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the keyword 'option', and set the date as a new Date object.

```
$("#has-assigned-date").datepicker('option', { 
   minDate: -20, 
   maxDate: "+12M +10D" , 
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",      
   defaultDate: dd, 
   setDate: new Date((def[2] - 1) + "/" + def[1] + "/" + def[0])
   });
```

Comment: `$("#has-assigned-date").datepicker({})` works fine when setting up a `datePicker`.  Also `setDate` is not an option, it should be `$("#has-assigned-date").datepicker('setDate'`.

Answer (score 1):

`setDate` needs to be called separately; it's not an option.

It also needs to be in the same format as the `dateFormat` ("yy-mm-dd"), or a Date object.

```
$("#has-assigned-date").datepicker({ 
   minDate: -20, 
   maxDate: "+12M +10D" , 
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",      
   defaultDate: dd, 
}).datepicker('setDate', new Date((def[2] - 1) + "/" + def[1] + "/" + def[0]));
```