# How to customize jquery ui date picker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, customization

I want to customize jquery ui date picker by setting server date as current date.

After refering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953840/datepickersetdate-issues-in-jquery)

i wrote down

```
var queryDate = '2012-11-15',
    dateParts = queryDate.match(/(\d+)/g)
    realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);  
                                // months are 0-based!


$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', realDate);
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

it works, but when i change second step to

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',minDate: 0,maxDate: '+6M' });
```

it shows dates according to the system date not the server date which i had assigned,

How to solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the value of the input field to be a value from the server side:

```
<script>
var queryDate = '2012-02-25';
var dateParts = queryDate.match(/(\d+)/g);

var realDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2]);

var min_date = new Date(2012, 2 - 1, 25 - 20); //feb 5 is the min date
var max_date = new Date(2012, 2 - 1, 25 + 1); //feb 26 is the max date

$( "#date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: min_date, maxDate: max_date});
$( "#date" ).datepicker("setDate", realDate);
</script>
```

In this case we are setting the date to 2012-02-25. In order for this to work you must set the format of the datepicker to be the same as the format that you've used for the value which is `'Y-m-d'`

Comment: i know, but that was not my question, i assign server date to date picker using setDate property, but when i try to limit date range, date picker has another property called minDate and maxDate. thus i assign a value to minDate and maxDate, but after this, it process according to the system date and it does not trigger the server date i assinged.

Comment: oops sorry didn't notice it the first time, I see the problem now. Give me time to play around with it :)

Comment: Ok. I've updated the code based on the original code that you've posted. Basically you have to set a date as the min and max date.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time spent for me.The code Worked well.

I have one more question, what if i want maxDate as +6M??

Comment: 6 months from the original date? you can just do something like `dateParts[1] + 6 - 1` for the second parameter