# JQuery Datepicker get date according to server date/time in MVC3 Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How to set the server date to Jquery Datepicker?

Because the user may change his system date and will do some manipulations.
I gone through many links for eg: [How to customize jquery ui date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889379/how-to-customize-jquery-ui-date-picker). This is not working.

Comment: On both the Controller and the Model side of things you can find out the server date/time. From there you are able to display it on the View (and subsequently adjust your DatePicker). Your primary error is to try to get it the other way round, from the View.

Answer (score 0):

Try do this code...

```
 $('input').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', '@DateTime.Now.ToString([FORMAT])');
```