# jQuery/JavaScript function not updating textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the Bootstrap DatePicker: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

I have it attached to two boxes - InvDate and InvDueDate - and it pops up ok, and sets the dates etc just fine.

I have a drop down box though, that when selected, I want to take the date in the InvDate box, and add the val() of the dropdownlist to the InvDate, and populate InvDueDate.

However, I cannot seem to get the InvDueDate to change it's date (does nothing) - the dropdown box does trigger the function, but this line doesn't appear to do anything:

`$("#InvDueDate").datepicker("setDate", duedate);`:

HTML is:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="InvDate">InvDate</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="textbox datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field InvDate must be a date." data-val-required="The InvDate field is required." id="InvDate" name="InvDate" type="text" value="02 May 2013" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="InvDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>



     <div class="editor-label">
       <label for="Terms">Terms</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      <select id="Terms" name="Terms"><option value="0">Due on invoice date</option>
        <option value="7">Net 7 days</option>
        <option value="14">Net 14 days</option>
        <option value="21">Net 21 days</option>
        <option value="28">Net 28 days</option>
        <option value="45">Net 45 days</option>
        <option value="60">Net 60 days</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="InvDueDate">InvDueDate</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">

        <input class="textbox datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field InvDueDate must be a date." data-val-required="The InvDueDate field is required." id="InvDueDate" name="InvDueDate" type="text" value="02 May 2013" />

        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="InvDueDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

My jQuery/Javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Terms").change(function () {
      var invdate = new Date();
      var duedate = new Date();
      invdate = $("#InvDate").val();
      var net = $("#Terms").val();
      duedate.setDate(invdate.getDate() + net);
      $("#InvDueDate").datepicker("setDate", duedate);
   });
  });
</script>
```

Is it obvious to anyone where I'm going wrong?

**UPDATE TO SHOW WORKING CODE**

```
    var start_date = new Date($('#InvDate').val());
    var duration = parseInt($('#Terms').val());
    var end_date = new Date();
    end_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + duration);
    $("#InvDueDate").datepicker("setDate", end_date);
```

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953840/datepickersetdate-issues-in-jquery)

Comment: Little tip : try debugging the dates with `console.log` to see if your `vars` are well formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your date is not correctly formatted, see :

```
var invdate = new Date();
```

and then it's replaced by

```
$('#invDate').val();
```

But it should be :

```
var invDate = new Date($('#invDate').val());
```

OR (as *zeroflagL* commented)

```
var invDate = $('#invDate').datepicker('getDate'); //gives you a Date object
```

Comment: or `var invDate = $('#invDate').datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: I agree, but in my memory the .val() on the datepicker field gives out the proper date format (not sure).

Comment: True, but if you directly can get a `Date` object ... ;) +1 anyway

Comment: Thank you - I've simplified the code based on comments and suggestions, and posted the "working" JS in the question.  Thanks again for everyone's input, I appreciate it.  Mark

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure setDate is a method available to $.datepicker? It's not listed in the documentation

This might be what your looking for? 
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker#update

Comment: See on the [github](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L288) it exists.