# jQuery Datepicker misbehavior submitting an input's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

When my site is loaded, my text input (name: fecha) for "date" default's value is today's. Now, even when I don't change that value or change it via jQuery's Datepicker, and it shows the correct value, when that input is submitted, it's value is changed to "1969-12-31".

I can't explain it. I even have set Datepicker's default date to today's.

Here's the code being used:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:1.5em;">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1" style="border:solid 1px #CCC; border-radius:4px;">Fecha:</span>
   <input type="text" name="fecha" style="position:relative;z-index=999" id="datepicker" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
     closeText: 'Cerrar',
     prevText: '<Ant',
     nextText: 'Sig>',
     currentText: 'Hoy',
     monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
     monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
     dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
     dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
     dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
     weekHeader: 'Sm',
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
     firstDay: 1,
     isRTL: false,
     showMonthAfterYear: false,
     yearSuffix: ''
     };
     $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);



    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
    });

    $("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Is there anything you can see am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [.datepicker('setdate') issues, in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953840/datepickersetdate-issues-in-jquery)

This line is your mistake:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: This seems to work, except I still have issues as the values for dat, month and year get mixed up when trying to format them with php date (). Thanks a lot!

Comment: In PHP is: `date("d/m/Y", time());` or if you have another set Date you can use `date("d/m/Y", strtotime($_POST['fecha']));`